# umbraco cms error when publishing

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Page not found

No umbraco document matches the url 'http://localhost:64018/'

umbraco tried this to match it using this xpath query'/root/* [@urlName = ""] | /root/*')

This page can be replaced with a custom 404 page by adding the id of the umbraco document to show as 404 page in the /config/umbracoSettings.config file. Just add the id to the '/settings/content/errors/error404' element.

For more information, visit information about custom 404 on the umbraco website.

This page is intentionally left ugly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This could be a few things. Is the site running on localhost port 64018? If not, then it looks like you have that set as the host name for the site. Change it to the correct host name, and it should start working again. Umbraco host names and ports don't play very well together, so if it IS running on that port and you have the host name set, remove the host name and see if that works.

Also, check that the page has a template assigned to it. If there's no template, the page will 404.

Comment: +1 for the mention about template. Totally forgot to assing a template to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's second suggestion is probably the right answer here. Go to your page in the Umbraco Admin. Click the properties tab on the page that's causing the issue and check the template. If there's no assigned template then the page will generate the error you mention. This is normally the reason for this error (assuming the rest of your site is working correctly).